# Php mysql select rows where column contain json_encode array name value = var

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column months `json_encode` array with these values:

```
 id  | months
  1  | {"january":"480.00","february":"480.00".....}
  2  | {"january":"500.00","february":"480.00".....}
  2  | {"january":"700.00","february":"480.00".....}
```

WHERE  `months->january = '480.00'`;

I would get all rows where `january = 480.00`

Return id `1`

Comment: `where months like '%january";"480.00"%'`

Comment: Does your column have the JSON datatype?